# Unchangable fixed attribute value and the element date's format

Tags: html, xml, xslt, web, xsd

i have to questions about the internet tv site i'm working on.
first question is that the main element which is subscription has an **attribute** called (ServerIP) I want the server ip to be fixed and i want to give it a value that can never be changed. i tried this code but it didn't work, it prints nothing when i try to print it unless i give it a value in XML

```
<xs:attribute name="serverIP" type="xs:string" fixed="10.144.50.55"/>
```

The second question is, if i have an **element** called date,and i want to give it a specific pattern yyyy-mm-dd. i know i can do it for attributes using simple type. i tried this code but it didn't work

```
 <xs:element name="dateOfBirth" type="xs:date">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                        <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:pattern value="d{4}[-]d{2}[-]d{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                    </xs:element>
```

how do i know that my code worked? because when i give it a value in the format yyyymmdd in XML file it gets printed in the same format not like yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: You would need an XSLT 2.0 **schema-aware** processor to make this work. Hint: the processor in Firefox (or any other browser) is neither. However, you can still make these adjustments within your XSLT stylesheet. You just need to use the XSLT language, not XSD.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question - it depends on your XSLT Processor that you should mention in your question. Adjusting your attribute from

```
<xs:attribute name="serverIP" type="xs:string" fixed="10.144.50.55"/>
```

to

```
<xs:attribute name="serverIP" select="'10.144.50.55'"/>
```

keeps the value for e.g. Saxon 9.5.1.6 HE.  [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsS/1)

For e.g. Saxon 6.5. it would be

```
<server>
      <xsl:attribute name="serverIP">10.144.50.55</xsl:attribute>
</server>
```

[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsS)

Though I was unable to find an online XSLT-Processor handling the fixed-attribute I'd just guess it could work adjusting your current attribute to

```
<xs:attribute name="serverIP" type="xs:string" fixed="'10.144.50.55'"/>
```

**Update** for the comment: You can also try to declare a static parameter at the beginning of your XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" 
    omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:param name="staticServer" select="'10.144.50.55'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <head>
      <server>
      <xsl:attribute name="serverIP" select="$staticServer"/></server>
    </head>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>
```

But it also depends on your unknown XSLT Processor if this approach will work.
[Demo](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsS/2)

**Update** for the comment: As just being mentioned that Notepad++ is used, question is if any XSLT is applied to modify the output. If not, you could check e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/148177/notepad-or-other-application-to-replace-string-with-numeric-function  as example.

Comment: Still doesn't work. what i need is to make serverIP fixed and never be changed and the user **doesn't need to give it a value because it already has one**

Comment: @user3633859 Just updated my answer with an additional approach. It'd be easier if you could update in your question which XSLT Processor you're using, and which version of XSLT.

Comment: what do you mean by XSLT processor? I'm using notepad++ to write my codes and firefox to view my pages. thank you will read your answer now

Comment: in the static parameter, can i say fixed="10.144.50.55" instead of select="10.144.50.55" because i'm asked to make it **fixed**

Comment: @user3633859 Which result do you get when using `select="'10.144.50.55'"` (so the ip in the select is wrapped in `''`)?

Comment: i tried putting select instead of fixed, it also prints nothing while it's supposed to print 10.144.50.55, in the xml.

Comment: @user3633859 And what do you get for `<xsl:attribute name="serverIP">10.144.50.55</xsl:attribute>`? 
And just to be sure - are you applying any XSLT to the XML to modify the output?

Comment: i still get nothing. i don't understand your questin but i have other elements and attributes and they work fine but this is the only one that i want to give it these features "fixed+unchangable+already assigned"